# TortoiseHg: "TortoisePlink.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have been stuck with this problem for almost a day now and finally decided to shout-out for help.

Things I have already done:

- Updated my .ini file with:

[ui] 
username = User Name
ssh = "C:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 -batch -C

also tried,

ssh = "C:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 -batch -C -i C:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseHg\ssh_keys\my_rsa_key.ppk

---

- Environmental variables set to "PATH = ;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg"

---

- Current directory .ini file set to 
  [paths]
  default-push = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/Username/test_repo

---

I get an error:

remote: http 404 not found.When I back-traced it I realized TortoisePlink.exe is not running. I don't have Putty installed alongside TortoiseHg. Is it necessary I do?

Answer (score 29):

This relates to the latest version of TortoiseHG (3.5). I just installed it and received the same message. I found this after a search - just adding this in case others do the same.

With version 3.5 TortoisePlink.exe is contained in the **C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib** folder. 
Two solutions:
1) Copy TortoisePlink.exe into **C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg**
or
2) Add **;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib** to the environment PATH (needs a restart). 
For some reason TortoiseHG installer only adds "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg" to the PATH.

I used 2) and it worked immediately after re-start.

Comment: Thank you. I rebooted after installing TortoiseHg 3.5, and I still got that error. I used (1) (move TortoisePlink.exe up one folder level) and it worked immediately for me, no second restart necessary.

Comment: Also look at Mercurial.ini file for absolute paths to TortoisePlink.exe

Comment: Simpler solution 3):   since you already have an absolute path to `TortoisePlink.exe` in your `mercurial.ini` file, just edit that path to include the extra `\lib`

Answer (score 2):

Had you updated your version of TortoiseHg recently?  I just ran into this same issue after having done so and found your question.  (I'm now on TortoiseHg 2.10.1 with Mercurial 2.8.1.)

I had read a few people suggesting that there was a change to one or more environmental variables, but nothing concrete enough to link to here.  The release notes show that 2.8 has a change, but doesn't sound breaking:  [customtools: add 'workingdir' setting, {FILES} and {ALLFILES} variables](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/ReleaseNotes)

I decided to reboot to make sure I had a all the environmental variables loaded and after having done so, I discovered everything was working again.  I think it could have been a new environmental variable, but again... pure speculation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Turns out I set everything up correctly in my default settings (with an explicit path to TortoisePlink.exe), but I had it overridden in my project-specific settings without the path or other command-line switches set correctly. So if you get here, that's something else to check.